# How to make material components work with Karma in unit testing Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have an angular CLI project set up. I've made a form that uses angular material components, like `<md-card>`.

I'm just starting out with writing my first Karma/Jasmine unit test, following the steps in the [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#simple-component-test).

This is my component template:

```
<md-card [ngClass]="'dialog-card'">
<md-card-title [ngClass]="'dialog-title'">
    {{title}}
</md-card-title>
<md-card-content>

    <form (ngSubmit)="login()" #loginForm="ngForm">

        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <input md-input [(ngModel)]="user.email" 
                name="userEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email" 
                ngControl="userEmail" 
            required>
        </md-input-container>
        <br>

        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <input md-input [(ngModel)]="user.password" 
                name="userPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" 
                ngControl="userPassword" 
            required>
        </md-input-container>
        <br>

        <tm-message msgText="Wrong username or password" *ngIf="showError"></tm-message>
        <br>


        <button md-button type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid">Login</button>

        <p (click)="openForgotPasswordModal()">Forgot Password?</p>

    </form>

</md-card-content>
```

This is my karma spec:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule, MdDialogRef, MdDialog  } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { TmLoginComponent } from './tm-login.component';
import { TmMessageComponent } from '../../shared/components/tm-message.component';
import { UserAuthenticationService } from '../login/user-authentication.service';

describe('TmLoginComponent (inline template)', () => {

let comp: TmLoginComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture < TmLoginComponent > ;
let de: DebugElement;
let el: HTMLElement;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [TmLoginComponent, TmMessageComponent], // declare the test component
        imports: [MaterialModule, FormsModule,
            RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
                [{
                    path: 'login',
                    component: TmLoginComponent
                }, ])
        ],
        providers: [UserAuthenticationService],

    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TmLoginComponent);

    comp = fixture.componentInstance; // TmLoginComponent test instance

    // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.title'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
});

    it('should display original title', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(el.textContent).toContain(comp.title);
    });
});
```

At this point, I'm just trying to run the basic unit test that the title is being displayed properly.

However, I'm getting a lot of material specific errors. Like

> No provider for MdDialog.

I'm opening an md Dialog on clicking a link. THe code is in the (fairly long) .ts file, but that's not the issue here.

Where would I add MdDialog in the testbed? If I add it to providers, I get the error: "no provider for overlay". I don't know how to fix that.

Is there any way I can configure karma to include all material components at start?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All the providers are provided by calling `forRoot()` on the module

```ts
imports: [ MaterialModule.forRoot() ]
```

For versions `2.0.0-beta.4` and later (since the `forRoot` method has been removed):

```ts
imports: [ MaterialModule ]
```

For versions `2.0.0-beta.11` and later, since `MaterialModule` has been removed, you have to import the modules you require for your test cases yourself:

```ts
imports: [ MatButtonModule, MatDialogModule ]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did that. Now I have `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null`

Comment: I don't see any element (in your template) with a `title` class. I see a `dialog-title` class though

Comment: Do I need an element with a title class?

Comment: `de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.title'))`. Why do you think it (`de`) is undefined.

Comment: So sorry. I guess it regressed at some point. Still, I changed the class form `dialog-title` to `title` class and it still threw the same error. Then I created simple `<p class='title'>{{title}}</p>` and it worked. I don't get it. Is it an issue with `ngClass`?

Comment: I don't, but why are you using `ngClass` anyway for just a simple string? Just use `class`. If you actually need to evaluate an expression, that's different

Comment: You can always just print out the HTML content of the whole `fixture.nativeElemen.innerHTML`. Maybe that will show you what is actually being rendered (maybe give you a hint as to what's going on)

Comment: BTW, is there anything I could do in the karma conf file so I don't have to import material in each spec file?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 15):

Current technique calls for individual imports of Angular Material modules, as `MaterialModule` is deprecated and [was removed in 2.0.0-beta.11](https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.11):

```
import {
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule
} from '@angular/material';
```

Then add the same list as imports in the TestBed config:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ ... ],
        imports: [
            MatButtonModule,
            MatIconModule,
            ...
        ],
        providers: [ ... ]
    })
        .compileComponents();
}));
```

Answer (score 6):

I've been struggling with this as well today and you need to mock out the necessary classes yourself by using providers in jasmine. It's a hassle and I wish there was a better way but at least no more errors...

If anyone has a better idea, please enlighten the rest of the community!

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AlertDialogComponent } from './alert-dialog.component';
import { MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

describe('AlertDialogComponent', () => {
  let component: AlertDialogComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AlertDialogComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MatDialogModule],
      declarations: [AlertDialogComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {}
        },
        {
          provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue:{}
        }
     ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```